# flush_rewrite_rules - Missing Rules

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, flush, rules

We've had this ongoing Wordpress bug that has transcended multiple versions of WP (3.5 - 4.3) and different versions of cache (memcache, redis).

When we visit the permalinks page or flush the rewrite rules (via an action or WP-CLI), there are missing rewrite rules.  So if we have 420 rules, 265 are showing up in the DB.  I thought it might be a caching issue, but after checking the DB options table, confirmed it wasn't.

We don't see this bug on our local, integration or staging envs, only our production.  Which leads me to believe it is traffic related?  What happens if a request is made during the flush before it's completed building the rules?

Any ideas?

Comment: php max execution time?

Comment: currently set at 180.  max_execution_time = 180

Comment: id say up it a little, it sounds ok but depending on server load ...

Comment: Strange.  Now it's just not getting to the update_option part of the script.  It's deleted the rewrite_rules row, but not rebuilding it at all.

Comment: well its either the max execution time or memory limit and it sounds like one has decreased. Try disabling all plugins/ themes and create a bones theme with just the rewrite rules if still having issues,  Id say confirm the php changes have taken place and then look at creating debug logs to see how far you are getting. If its not php, its mysql (unlikely, but could be slow).

Comment: Figured it out.  I think it's a WP core issue with scalability. Heavy traffic was causing parse_request to enter a conditional it shouldn't have and set the rewrite rules.  Here is the gist for my solution to submit to WP.

https://gist.github.com/andyphillips82/9bd0cdab46dd01638181693343e08c72